Azure DevOps Server – damaged configuration database causing big problems
We are running Azure DevOps Server 2022 on Windows Server 2019 with SQL Server 2019.
The AzureDevOps_Configuration database got damaged some time ago, a rename within the Administration Console went wrong.
Now we have a range of problems:

The Admin Console shows an empty collections window
We can’t configure backups – TF400982 error
We can’t make any changes.
In the Admin Console, we see no collection.
TFSConfig commands run forever without success.

All projects are working fine, but we can’t make any configuration changes, we can’t update to 2022.1 or 2022.2RC.
It’s a production server, I can’t just re-install everything, and can’t risk experimenting. I tried replicating all databases on a similar setup on a local VM, but of course the software knows it’s running on a different machine.
In short, the collection databases seem to be just fine, the configuration one not that fine.
What are my options? I would like to

detach the collection databases via TfsConfig,
backup the detached databases,
delete all databases in SQL Server,
install 2022.2RC update as a new deployment, and then
restore and attach the detached databases.

Would this be a reasonable approach?
Is there a way to force a proper detach? Or any third party tools?
I can’t believe that the whole DevOps installation should need a complete re-install, losing all data, because of a problem in the configuration database, and would be very grateful for any sort of help!
Tried backing up all databases via the Database Backup Tool (option on the Attach dialog).
It backs up the databases as they are, still in attached state, so I can't attach them to a new installation.

Is it important to illustrate how did you rename it in details

Good point. I renamed a no longer needed collection within the Server Admin Console by

stopping the collection
editing settings
renamed in the collection settings to "CollectionToBeDeleted".

This "CollectionToBeDeleted" never existed as a database, but it's still in the AzureDevOps_Configuration database.
The original database still exists, but, as the collections window in the admin console is empty, it's not shown there. I copied the configuration and that database to a test VM and attached it, it shows the renamed one online, the original as "Offline (Attaching)".

On a local VM with Windows-, SQL, and DevOps Server I tried creating a few collections and projects, detaching them all, backing databases up, removing all databases and DevOps, then re-installing DevOps, restoring all databases except AzureDevOps_Configuration, and attaching the restored ones.
It worked nicely, and seems to have re-created the confiuration.
Before I try that on the production server: Does anyone have ideas or suggestions how to detach when the configuration is damaged? A "force-detach"?

To answer my own question, as it might help someone in a similar situation:
I have been able to rebuild the configuration database, so, at least for me, this approach worked:

Detach all collections via the command line interface: tfsconfig collection /detach /collectionName:Foo (note: The collection name has to be typed without the "Tfs_" or "AzureDevOps_")
Back up the detached databases from SQL Server
Delete SQL Server databases, including the _Configuration database
Restore the backed up databases
Re-install DevOps
From the DevOps Server UI, attach the restored collections.

It's not strictly required to delete all server databases, in my case it helped, as I had left over databases connected to nothing. Deleting them all, and restoring only required collections. brought back a tidy and nicely working system.
